# Android - Interactive shell (Runtime.getRuntime().exec())

Tags: android, shell, process, bufferedreader, interactive

How to run an interactive shell on android? (rooted device)

I need the nexts steps:

1 - Execute shell process (onCreate)

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[]{"su","-c","sh"});
```

2 - Get the output (onCreate)

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream));
//dos is a field (a class attribute)
dos = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         String l;
         //wait the console output and write it
         while((l = br.readLine()) != null) {
              Log.v("info", l);
         }
    }
}).start();
```

3 - Execute a command (Button -> onClick())

```
cmd("wpa_cli");
```

The cmd method is:

```
public void cmd(String cmd) {
   dos.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");
   dos.flush();
}
```

The Log never shows the console output.

Next step:

4 - Get the output of a subcommand of wpa_cli (another Button -> onClick())

```
cmd("help");
```

Should show the wpa_cli help but it doesn't work.
If i press the button many times appears incomplete output (help)

What is the correct way to initialize a process when the Activity is creating and keep it active to interact?

Thanks.

PostData
I replaced the line `Log.v("info", l);` 
with

```
fos.write(l);
Message msg = handlerTest.obtainMessage();
msg.obj = l;
handlerTest.sendMessage(msg);
```

fos -> FileOutputStream object

```
Handler handlerTest = new Handler() {
    @Override
    handleMessage(Message msg) {
       if (msg != null) {
         //alert... (String)msg.obj;
       }
    }
};
```

And only displays the alert from the direct commands, as `help` for example. The command `status` only work when the stream is closed. (after execute `cmd("quit");` and `cmd("exit");`)

I don't understand. stdout is more that one? I can interact with the output without close the stream?

With `adb shell` i read the output file (created after closing the stream) and it's complete.

PostData2:

The problem is the buffer. Between the binary file (executed) output and java process i can disable the buffer without using Native I/O?
The Android Terminal Emulator works fine, it's using NIO?

Comment: Take a look at this post - in particular where it talks about flushing and redirecting any how it differs by OS: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2

Comment: @Mick In all examples are expected the end of process. In my case it is undeterminated; I need to receive data from the process before the process ends. (interact with it) I think it must be some PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream with a Channel. I keep looking for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

Without using the tool `stdbuf` (of coreutils) in Android I found the next solution:

I'm using two processes called process1 and process2: both -> `new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"su", "-c", "sh"}).start();`

In the first process I run `wpa_cli`

```
dos1.write("wpa_cli".getBytes());
dos1.flush();
```

In a thread I wait 5 seconds and run wpa_cli in the second process.

```
dos2.write("wpa_cli".getBytes());
dos2.flush();
```

To get the output from wpa_cli is necessary to close it with `quit`

```
dos1.write("quit".getBytes());
dos1.flush();
```

The main thread that work with both processes:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    boolean firstProcess = true;
                    while (follow) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (follow) {
                            if (firstProcess) {
                                cmd("wpa_cli", dos2);
                                cmd("quit", dos1);
                            } else {
                                cmd("wpa_cli", dos1);
                                cmd("quit", dos2);
                            }
                            firstProcess = !firstProcess;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

**Important**: Both processes have this (when the process is created):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process1.getInputStream()));
                        String l;
                        try {
                            Message msg;
                            while ((l = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                msg = handlerStdout.obtainMessage();
                                msg.obj = l;
                                handlerStdout.sendMessage(msg);
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

The handler `handlerStdout` does the desired job. It receives the output of `wpa_cli` every 5 seconds: the output comes from process1 and process2 alternatively

---

An alternative solution would be to compile coreutils or `stdbuf` for Android. Or install compiled coreutils from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2613243 (for me not work `stdbuf` because the `libstdbuf.so` not found)

With `stdbuf -oL wpa_cli` the output isn't buffered (buffer one line). Without it the output is buffered (4k).

Comment: I don't understand how works StackOverflow. This was my answer.

Comment: @VasileM You put your answer in your own question. As it's not a correct way to have a solution, I moved it away from your question and put it in an answer of its own, [as seen by the revision history of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31296374/revisions). I made it a community wiki, but if you prefer to post it under your account, feel free to do it, and then quickly tell me so I can delete the community wiki post. You can have [the source code of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1ef2512e-ea37-460b-bf20-c175baf4f54b/view-source) from the revision history too.

Comment: @VasileM alternatively, you may simply accept this community wiki post (with the green checkmark).