# How do I need to read getevent, to be able to withdraw and process?

Tags: android

I have completed

```
try {   
      Runtime.getRuntime () exec ( "su");   
      Runtime.getRuntime () exec ( "getevent"); 
     } 
Catch (IOException e) {}
```

What you need to continue to perform to consistently read the values of touch (event0) for processing?

Comment: @VasileM Hello! I met your work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296374/resolved-android-interactive-shell-runtime-getruntime-exec
I also have a problem that you need to change the InputStream buffering, to receive timely getevent touch.
Can you help me?

Comment: @VasilieM need your help...